# 2 column n rows array- operation on elements of two colums in each row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of n rows and two columns (array).
I have another variable (a) which I am using as reference.

```
 for a between (1-10000)
     if    column1 of ARRAY<= a <= column2 of the ARRAY
            save the tuple (a, YES)
```

This resultant tuple I will use for further operation

Comment: Produce a [`mcve`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: fluff, spelling

Answer (score 0):

The [NumPy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.html) has all the information you may need.